# Incorrect return value after calling getTransactionCount

Tags: web3js, transactions, raw-transaction, binance

I have only few lines in the code:

```js
async function test() {
   await web3.eth.getTransactionCount('{ WALLET }').then(console.log);
}
test();
```

The return values are random: 0, 22 (this is the real value), 8, 3.. How is it possible? I tried ankr, quicknode, always the same. Network: BSC

Comment: so what happens if you do this via `curl` to the RPC server using `eth_getTransactionCount`  as method name and the address as `params` ?

Comment: @Nulik I got the same result. It looks like the node is 1000 blocks behind the mainnet.